# Why is it JSReact will let me call React Native but then won't identify appropriate syntax and color coding?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

Specifically at points such as this

```
    componentDidMount() {
    this._getCoords();
}
```

the "{" which comes before this`._getCoords` is marked as wrong. As is the "{" after

```
    constructor(props)(
    super(props);
    this._getCoords = this._getCoords.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        position: null
        };
```

Is there any reason for this? Instead of accepting the { as valid, it says a ) is expected instead.. But when I put in that suggestion the code obviously breaks.

I have tried to use tools such as "ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets", "React-Native/React/Redux snippets for es6/es7", and "React Native Tools"... But none of them seem to allow me to properly write React Native code.

I've attempted to turn extensions on and off without much difference being seen. It seems like VSCode wants me to purely code in JavaScript

```
    constructor(props)(
    super(props);
    this._getCoords = this._getCoords.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        position: null
    }; 

    componentDidMount() {
    this._getCoords();
    }
```

As previously state the general error I am seeing is ";" expected or ") expected" instead of accepting the appropriate syntax of React Native. Additionally, although this is more visual, the color-coded nature of various commands isn't appearing.

### Edit

```js
 import {MapView } from 'react-native-maps'; 


 constructor(props){ 
super(props); 
this._getCoords = this._getCoords.bind(this); 
this.state = { position: null }; 
} 

componentDidMount() { this._getCoords(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include a constructor, you must use `middle brackets` instead of `small brackets`.

> ( => { //   `{` instead of `(`

JavaScript is based on Java and is an object-oriented language. Therefore, you create objects in the class. To use the constructor, you must use a class.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      position: null
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this._getCoords();
  }

  _getCoords() {
     alert("_getCoords")
  }
  render() {
    return(<View><Text>Basic Screen </Text> </View>);

  }
}
```

Comment: Even with your code put in, the error or " ';' is expected" still comes up. Could it have anything to do with not being able to select "React Native" specifically, having to write in JavaScript React instead?

Comment: The following code is what I replaced:


import {MapView
} 
from 'react-native-maps';

constructor(props)(
    super(props);
    this._getCoords = this._getCoords.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        position: null
        ); 
    }

componentDidMount() {
    this._getCoords();
}

TO 

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this._getCoords = this._getCoords.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        position: null
        }; 
    }

componentDidMount() {
    this._getCoords();
}
Where the (/{ is, ; is expected

Comment: Where is your class ??

Comment: It's in there... was just not included to save space. Sorry for that. Should've probably included it, huh?

Comment: @Szatmar Look at my revised answer.

Comment: Would you like to select the 'V' symbol and arrow if the answer was helpful?